# Declare variable in Bash?

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, variables

I'm connected to my DB from the bash. I do a select count of an array and I want to stock the return in a variable. How can I do that?

I did:

```
var=`"select count(*) from shop_tab where catalog <> ''" | mysql -h abcdcef.com --port=3306 --user=root --password=hbbfe shop`
```

The request return a number but it doesn't stock into the variable.

Thanks!

EDIT: It works with this command line:

```
myvar = $(echo "select count(*) from shop_tab where catalog <> '';" | mysql -h abcdcef.com --port=3306 --user=root --password=hbbfe shop)
```

Comment: How do you know it is not in the variable?

Comment: What is the content of `var` after you run this? (`echo $var`)

Comment: Yes i did echo $var, there is nothing, a blank..

Comment: Does this help?
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636977/bash-script-select-from-database-into-variable][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636977/bash-script-select-from-database-into-variable

Comment: You have to do it all on one line, since the variable isn't being exported: `var=XmycommandX; echo $var` (replace `X` by the backtick, I don't know how to escape the backtick in the comment box). Also use `-e` rather than piping.

Comment: @Raanan W thanks, I figured out!

Comment: @user: see my answer, I completed it.

Answer (score 4):

An easier way is :

```
var=$(mysql -h abcdcef.com --port=3306 --user=root --password=hbbfe --batch --skip-column-names -Dshop -e "select count(*) from shop_tab where catalog <> ''")
```

Moreover, I'll preconize the use of function in order to easily add options to the MySQL command without having to modifying all your script.

```
function MysqlQuery() {
    mysql -h abcdcef.com --port=3306 --user=root --password=hbbfe --batch --skip-column-names -D "$1" -e "$2";
}

va=$(MysqlQuery Shop "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM shop_tab WHERE catalog <> ''")
vaABC=$(MysqlQuery Shop "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM shop_tab WHERE catalog <> 'abc'")
vadef=$(MysqlQuery Shop "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM shop_tab WHERE catalog <> 'def'")
# ...
```

I find this more readable too...

Answer (score 1):

I think you are forgetting an `echo` in the pipe? Like this:

```
var=`echo "select count(*) from shop_tab where catalog <> ''" | mysql -h abcdcef.com --port=3306 --user=root --password=hbbfe shop`
```

Comment: Well spotted! One more reason not to do any piping at all and instead use `mysql -e`.