# Problem with return variable in bash

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, return-value

This mysql command line return me: **count(*) 19**. It's a big problem for me because I just want **19** to make a loop with this number. How can I do?

```
var = $(echo "select count(*) from shop_tab where catalog <> '';" | mysql -h abcdcef.com --port=3306 --user=root --password=hbbfe shop)
```

Comment: Try "select count(*) AS res from shop_tab where catalog <> '';"

Comment: Duplicate with : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6759397/declare-variable-in-bash/6759568#6759568

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pipe the result through `tail` to cut off the header:

```
... shop | tail -1)
```

Answer (score 6):

An easier way is :

```
var=$(mysql -h abcdcef.com --port=3306 --user=root --password=hbbfe --batch --skip-column-names -Dshop -e "select count(*) from shop_tab where catalog <> ''")
```

Moreover, I'll preconize the use of function in order to easily add options to the MySQL command without having to modifying all your script.

```
function MysqlQuery() {
    mysql -h abcdcef.com --port=3306 --user=root --password=hbbfe --batch --skip-column-names -D "$1" -e "$2";
}

va=$(MysqlQuery Shop "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM shop_tab WHERE catalog <> ''")
vaABC=$(MysqlQuery Shop "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM shop_tab WHERE catalog <> 'abc'")
vadef=$(MysqlQuery Shop "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM shop_tab WHERE catalog <> 'def'")
# ...
```

I find this more readable too...

Answer (score 2):

You can use awk or cut to get second value.

**awk**

```
var = $(echo "select count(*) from shop_tab where catalog <> '';" | mysql -h abcdcef.com --port=3306 --user=root --password=hbbfe shop | awk '{ print $2 }')
```

**cut**

```
var = $(echo "select count(*) from shop_tab where catalog <> '';" | mysql -h abcdcef.com --port=3306 --user=root --password=hbbfe shop | cut -d' ' -f2)
```