# Referencing mysql return in shellscript

Tags: mysql, bash, shell

I need to reference the output of this mysql code

```
mysql -h xx.xx.x.xx -u xxxxxx -pxxxxxx xxxx_xxxx < cmd.sql
```

that does a count(*) to check if that db table has been filled or not. Trying to grab the return for an if statement later in the script.

I've tried both

```
count=$(mysql -h xx.xx.x.xx -u xxxxxx -pxxxxxx xxxx_xxxx < cmd.sql)
if [ $count > 0 ]; then
    echo "record found\n"
fi
```

as well as

```
count=$(mysql -h xx.xx.x.xx -u xxxxxx -pxxxxxx xxxx_xxxx "select count(*) from xxxx_x")
if [ $count > 0 ]; then
    echo "record found\n"
fi
```

but they both got a "[: count(*): unary operator expected" error.

I even tried to "select count(specific_column) from xxx_xx" with the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want

```
if [ $count -gt 0 ]; then
```

The `>` is the output redirection operator (analogous to `<`, which you're using above)

To capture the *last* line, just pipe your results through `tail -1` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6763707/problem-with-return-variable-in-bash))

Comment: Thanks. I knew that was a problem but since the error wasn't on that line I didn't figure that it would be the issue. It fixed that error but now I get a "too many arguments" error. I suspect because the mysql command outputs 2 lines "count(*) | 0" How would I edit my code to only read the second line?