# Can MySQL give out non-zero return code when non-empty result set?

Tags: mysql, bash, shell

I am using Linux and MySQL 5.6

I run the mysql this way:

```
mysql --user=XXX --password=XXX < myfile.sql
```

Here is the content of myfile.sql

```
select * from account where balance < 0
```

What I want to do is that:

when there is at least one account with negative balance, give out a non-zero return code.

Then my script can check this situation like this:

```
mysql --user=XXX --password=XXX < myfile.sql
if [[ $? -gt 0 ]]
then
    echo ERROR: Negative balance
fi
```

Can I achieve this ?

Or, is there any alternate methods ?

2016-05-28 update:

Actually, my real life case is complicated.  I use this simple example is for easy expressing my problem.

Actually is there anything like the [ return ] statement in the shell script function so that I can give out different return codes according to different situations ?

For the accepted answer below, look like MySQL cannot generate a self-defined return code.  Putting a count(*) as the last line of the output display seems to be an alternative.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problem with return variable in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6763707/problem-with-return-variable-in-bash)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your SQL to count the rows, rather than return the data:

```
select COUNT(*) as total from account where balance < 0
```

Then capture the output which is the resulting *row data* (rather than the returned result code in $? which is just the *success* of the query execution), skip the first line (the column alias 'total') with sed, then the second line is your count of rows.

```
out=$(/opt/local/lib/mysql5/bin/mysql --user=XXX --password=XXX < myfile.sql | sed -n 2p)
if [[ $out -gt 0 ]]
then
    echo ERROR: Negative balance
fi
```

I've tested this in MacOSX not Linux, but the principle should be the same.

(And of course - you're not going to embed your database password in the source code, are you!)