# bash - SQL Query Outputs to variable

Tags: mysql, sql, bash, shell, variables

Im new in bash scripting.
I want to save sql-query outputs in variable, but

actually I must connect for every query to mysql with:

```
mysql -u $MYUSER -p$MYPASS -D database
```

and want to save every output in seperatly variable

sample query is: `SELECT domain FROM domains WHERE user='$USER'`

to

```
$variable1 = FIRST_OUTPUT
$variable2 = 2ND_OUTPUT
```

thank you

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Taken from [bash script - select from database into variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636977/bash-script-select-from-database-into-variable), you can read the query result into a variable.

#### Example

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM domains;
+-------+---------+
| user  | domain  |
+-------+---------+
| user1 | domain1 |
| user2 | domain2 |
| user3 | domain3 |
+-------+---------+
```

#### Usage

```
$ myvar=$(mysql -D$MYDB -u$MYUSER -p$MYPASS -se "SELECT domain FROM domains")
$ echo $myvar
domain1 domain2 domain3
```

`echo` is the bash command for output. You can then [split `$myvar` into separate variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886/how-do-i-split-a-string-on-a-delimiter-in-bash):

```
$ read var1 var2 var3 <<< $myvar
$ echo $var1
domain1
$ echo $var2
domain2
```

You can combine these two commands into a single one:

```
read var1 var2 var3 <<< $(mysql -D$MYDB -u$MYUSER -p$MYPASS -se "SELECT domain FROM domains")
```

It is possible to store the results into arrays (useful if you don't know how many records there):

```
$ read -ra vars <<< $(mysql -D$MYDB -u$MYUSER -p$MYPASS -se "SELECT domain FROM domains")
$ for i in "${vars[@]}"; do
$     echo $i
$ done
domain1
domain2
domain3
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way of doing is:

```
dbquery=`mysql -D$MYDB -u$MYUSER -p$MYPASS -se "SELECT domain FROM domains"`      
dbquery_array=( $( for i in $dbquery ; do echo $i ; done ) )
```

The first line stores all the output from the query in a varriable `dbquery` in a array-like-way. The second line converts the `dbquery` into an array `dbquery_array` with a simple `for` loop.

Answer (score 2):

I did this

variable=`mysql -u root -ppassworrd database << EOF
select MAX(variable) AS a from table where variable2 = 'SOMETEXT' AND day(datevalue) >= 22;
EOF`

I hope it helps