# How to extract data line by line from an MySQL database with BASH

Tags: php, mysql, bash

I don't quite understand how to extract all the datum from the MySQL [`my_database` database](http://postimg.org/image/wf1vbpavp/) by using BASH. Ideally I would like to extract the [data](http://postimg.org/image/wf1vbpavp/) line by line, and print it out into `mydata.csv` text file line by line [with an IFS].

My difficulty is how to read the lines individually, and have each of the columns separated with an infield separator "," .

I became even more perplexed after do some reading:

- http://www.garron.me/en/bits/mysql-select-multiple-conditions.html
- [bash script - select from database into variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636977/bash-script-select-from-database-into-variable)
- https://www.pantz.org/software/mysql/mysqlcommands.html

Any help is much appreciated!

I've thus far implemented

```
#!/bin/bash

myvariable=$(echo "SELECT * FROM cs_microrage_crm.stock_trans" | mysql -uUSER -pPASSWORD)

echo $myvariable
```

This results to `ERROR 1045 (28000):`

Comment: duplicate: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/196286/4667

Comment: You didn't make clear where your problem lies and show us your effort. Do you have problem interacting with the MySQL server? Do you have trouble forming your queries?

Comment: @4ae1e1, Currently I have a ERROR 1045 (28000), so I am trying to resolve that... :(

Comment: @3kstc Please expand on what you did and how you got that error, and put it into your question.

Comment: @4ae1e1 I've further added what I tried, there has been different things I've tried, all resulting to an `error 1045`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
dbName=foo;
sourseSet=$(mysql -uroot -pmysql -e "use $dbName; show tables;")
tableSet=$(echo $sourceSet | sed "s/Tables_in_$dbName //g")

for tb in $tableSet
do
    mysql -uroot -pmysql -e "use $dbName;\
    select * into outfile '/tmp/${tb}.csv'"\
    fields terminated by ','\
    lines ternimated by '\n'\
    from $tb"\
done
```